# 動画などを作成・編集することに関する質問はオントピックですか？

Tags: 討議, 話題の範囲

画像編集、音楽作成、動画編集などに関するソフトウェアの **使い方** についての質問は、日本語版スタック・オーバーフローにおいてオントピックでしょうか？

たとえば本家 Stack Overflow の [[photoshop] タグ](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/photoshop/info) には以下のように書かれています。

> If you're not scripting for Photoshop, then your question belongs on Super User, Photography, or Graphic Design.

ソフトウェア上で動かすスクリプトが関係してくる質問は日本語版でもオントピックでしょう。また、「Ubuntu 上で GIMP が動かない」「After Effects に MP4 ファイルがインポートできない」のような、ソフトウェアが使えるようになるまでに関する質問もオントピックにできそうだと感じています。

では、それ以外の質問はオントピックでしょうか？　具体的には以下のような形の質問を想定しています。

- 「Photoshop でレイヤーを作る方法」 「Audacity を使ってノイズを削除したい」 ([Super User](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic) っぽい質問の内、ソフトウェア自体の使い方に関するもの)
- 「Amazon のロゴのように矢印を文字へ食い込ませるには」 ([Graphic Design](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) っぽい質問)
- 「この写真の見栄えを良くする最適な明度」 ([Photography](https://photo.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) っぽい質問)

Answer (score 3):

<sup>(この回答は自己回答です。他のご意見を歓迎します。)</sup>

個人的には、動画などの編集の内容に直接関係する質問は、ソフトウェア開発やプログラミングとは少し距離のあるものであり、オフトピックになってしまうと考えています。

ただし、ゲーム開発やウェブ開発では当然いずれ各種メディアが必要になってくるので、質問の内容によっては上手く拾ってオントピックに寄せることは可能なのかもしれません (具体的には想像できていないのですが……)。