# Blender の使い方についての質問は、オントピックですか？

Tags: 討議, 話題の範囲

個人的に 3D モデリングにはまり、趣味で Blender を扱うようになりました。Blender にはたくさんの操作方法があり、なかなか使いこなすのに時間がかかります。そこで、Blender の操作についての質問をしたくなりました。

英語で良いなら、Stack Exchange Network には [Blender Stack Exchange](https://blender.stackexchange.com/) があります。しかし日本語で質問したくなった場合、Stack Exchange で扱えるのでしょうか。

そこで質問です。面や頂点の手動による編集や、マテリアルの設定など、Blender の操作に関する質問は、スタック・オーバーフローでオントピックですか？

### 参考

以下、参考情報です。

- 過去にいくつか質問がなされていたようです。

  - [「エディットモード中の見えていない部分の辺や頂点を非表示にしたい」](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/40567/19110)
  - [「Blenderの「User Preferences」での変更が反映されない事例」](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/33703/19110)
- Blender の Python API を扱うプログラミングについての質問は明らかにオントピックでしょうから、今回は考えません。
- 話をより広げると、3D モデリングソフト一般や、CAD ソフトなどにも同じ議論ができるかもしれませんが、この投稿では議論を簡明にするため Blender に話を限定させてください。
- 関連: https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic
- 関連: [「プログラムに関する質問か？そうでないか？」](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1556/19110)
- 関連: [「動画などを作成・編集することに関する質問はオントピックですか？」](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2589/19110)

Comment: 「3D モデリングソフト一般ではなく Blender に限定する」と釘を刺されてしまうと、Blender に精通したユーザーにしか意見が出せないように思います。
そして、どうやらそういうユーザーはいないようです。
質問者さんは、3D モデリングソフト一般と Blender は事情が異なり、Blender に特化した議論がなりたつとお考えかと思います。
もしそうであれば、その理由（おそらく Blender 特有の機能、あるいは使用用途などに由来するものと想像します）を説明いただければ、議論に参加できるユーザーが増えるかも知れません。

Comment: @mjy コメントありがとうございます。良い気付きがありました。私は元々、3D モデリング一般に話を広げると話が具体化しにくくて議論しにくいかなあと思って Blender に限定しました。他のものには違う点があって議論が拡散するかもしれないので、論点を狭めたのです（他との違いにはあまり詳しくありません）。しかしこれにはご指摘のように、議論できる方も狭めてしまうという欠点があったようです。おそらく質問の形を変えるべきですね。ご指摘ありがたいです。

Comment: Blender 特有の話というと、Blender には Blender に特化したサイトがある一方、Metasequoia や Sculptris、あるいは Autodesk 商品にはそれに特化したサイトが無い、というのが、話題を限定しようと思った発端かもしれないな、と今思い出しました。

Comment: 関連: そもそも Blender.SE を除く Stack Exchange Network において 3D モデリングソフト関連の質問はあまりなされていないようなので、議論の範囲を広げても無理筋っぽいな、と思い始めました: [Which Stack Exchange site is best for AutoCAD questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/188052/341401)

Answer (score 2):

私個人的には、Blender の操作のみについての質問はオフトピック気味だ、と思うようになりました。特に、画像編集のやり方や音声編集のやり方に関する質問と同様、プログラミングやソフトウェア開発が主眼にあるのではなく、メディアの作成が主目的であるような質問はオフトピックだと思います。

もちろんゲーム制作などプログラミングをする過程で 3D モデリングが必要になる場面もあります。「(何かしらライブラリ) で使うために 3D モデルをどう設定すればよい？」などの質問はオントピックにできるでしょう。また、Blender API を使ってプログラミングしている質問もオントピックです。

しかし一般的にはオフトピックとなり、他の質問サイトに誘導する形になるだろうと思いました。