# 電子回路に関する話題はオントピックですか？

Tags: 討議, 話題の範囲

スタック・オーバーフローにおいて、「電子回路」関連の質問が時折投稿されます。

**例:**

- [コンデンサと電圧と電流の関係について](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/90145)

「プログラミングか」という視点で考えると個人的には外れるように思いますが、クローズ投票でも判断に迷っている人が多い / 評価が割れている印象です。

例に挙げた投稿も含めて、いざ質問があると詳しい回答が付くケースも多いので、クローズで切り捨ててしまうものもったいない気もします。

オントピックとして扱うのであれば、より適切なタグ付けを行うなどで整理したいです。

**参考:**

- 英語版においては [circuit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/circuit) というタグがあるようです。
- 一方で、クローズ理由として "[because it's about electronic circuit design, not programming.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/375103)" で
  クローズ投票されているケースもあるようです (実際にクローズに至ったのかまではわかりません)。

Comment: 英語版には Electronics SE や Super User があるので日本語版 SO と事情が違いますが、英語版 SO だと以下の議論を見つけました: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/354015/5989200 、 https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/386455/5989200

Answer (score 12):

回答つけてる立場としては、組み込み系プログラマ（特にハードウエアに直接関連するデバイスドライバ等を組む人）には電子回路の知識は必須であるから切り捨てるのはもったいないじゃん、ということにつきます。 SPI ってなんぞ I2C ってなんぞ、とかいうのはデバイスドライバプログラマは知っていて当然であるべき事項であるため、オントピックであるとオイラは判断しています。

では時定数（τ＝CR）とかオームの法則とかキルヒホッフの法則とかは純ハードウエアの話なので、モデレータなりコミュニティの多数決によって排除すると定めたならオフトピックでもいいと思います。が、コミュニティの少数派として、せっかく投稿された質問トピックに回答ができるなら回答つけたいと思いますので**オイラがそのように行動する**ことは排除してほしくないです。

排除するならするで、ではどこに質問すればいいの？ってあたりは誘導してあげるべきだし（オイラなら誘導ではなく回答しますが）誘導先がないのなら受け入れてもいいと判断します。 https://electronics.stackexchange.com/ に相当するサイトの日本語版は現状ありませんし。

排除するなら spresense の使い方等の質問もすべて排除するべきなのでは？とか思ったりもします。（特定のとある製品の質疑応答に so 使うのもおかしな話）

---

コメント欄で続けるのもアレなので回答として

オイラ的にはオントピオフトピとか結構どうでもよくて、トピック最初の発言（まあ質問ですわな）がネタ的に気に入って、オイラが回答できる・コメントできるのなら回答・コメントしてもいい程度のノリです。結果的に元質問者の問題が解決したのならヨシ、解決しなくてもオイラの人生には関係ありません。参考になったチェックがついてもつかなくても upvote/downvote がついてもつかなくてもどうでもいいです。 SO 的「ナレッジベースの蓄積」に役立ってもいいし役立たなくてもいい。単に場所を提供してくれているなら使おう、ってだけです。なので「オントピ？オフトピ？」をこんなに議論している必然も理解できません。場所とはつまり大多数読者って意味になるのでしょうが、場所にふさわしい質問なら回答が付くだろうし、ふさわしくない質問なら回答が付かない。後者なら質問者にとってこの場所は役に立たないと判断したらよそに行くだろうし downvote がいっぱいついた質問っていずれ削除されるんでしょ、だったらそれまでほおっておけばいいぢゃん、なんて思っています。

Comment: 回答の本筋とはずれますが、Stack Overflow 的にはむしろ特定の製品の質疑応答にサイトを使うこと自体は推奨しています https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/product-support

Comment: 電子回路の話題ガオントピックなのかオフトピックなのかという議論と、オフトピックであった場合にどうすべきかという議論は、分けて考えた方が結論がつけやすそうだと思いました。こちらの回答には現時点で +8 投票が集まっていますが、回答の内容としては純ハードウェアの話がオントピック・オフトピックどちらなのかはやや曖昧になっており、投票された方はどちらの意見なのだろうかと悩んでいます。

Comment: いまどき本当に純ハードウエアな話題ってどんだけあるんですかね？　オイラの組み込み系のお仕事でも不可分っぽい話ばっかりですよ。一部ハード一部ソフトみたいな感じ。 https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/51412/ なんかもそんな話題。オイラ的には「オフトピは絶対排除」みたいな掲示板には近づきたくないっス。敷居高杉

Comment: はい、グラデーションがあるのは私の回答でも触れたとおりです。一方で気になっているのは、そのグラデーションのどこかからがオフトピックになるのか、それともすべてオントピックになるのか、です。オフトピックにされた場合どうするかは一旦おいておいて、まずオフトピックになりうるのかに興味があります。たとえば今回の質問に挙がった[コンデンサの質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/90145/19110)はかなりハードウェア寄りの質問だと思うのですが、これは 774RR さんの意見だとオントピックなのでしょうか、オフトピックなのでしょうか。

Answer (score 5):

要約：グラデーションがあるので、ソフトウェア開発やプログラミングに関係していそうかどうか、コミュニティで都度判断することになるでしょう。個人的には、今回のコンデンサの話はオフトピック寄りだと考えています。

---

SOja がオントピックとしている[ソフトウェア開発](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)と、電子回路などに代表される電気工学との間に明確な境界線を引くことは難しいな、とよく考えています。

- CPU アーキテクチャに関する質問をしようとするとどこかでハードウェアの話になって多少は電気的な要素が含まれます。
- デバイスドライバーのインストール方法は一応ソフトウェアの話です。
- ハードウェア記述言語によるプログラミングはソフトウェアというよりかはハードウェアです。
- フリップフロップ回路はかなり電気寄りですが、コンピューターの動作原理を知るのに重要ではあります。

自分は SOja がプログラミングをするにあたって便利な日本語のナレッジベースとなれるように、オントピックになる話題の範囲をどちらかというと広めに解釈したいと考えています。このためたとえば、[ラズパイに SD カードが認識されないという質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/34750/19110)のように、質問の中だけではプログラミングは行っていないしプログラマーがよく使うソフトウェアに関してもいない質問を、特にオフトピック通報せずに放っておいたりしています。これは、直接はソフトウェア開発に関係していなくても、間接的には関係していると信じているからです。

とはいえ、話題の範囲を無限に広く取ることはできません。そうなってしまうとモデレーションなどのサイトの運営が現実的には難しくなってしまいますし、サイトのアイデンティティが薄れてしまいます。このためどこかに境界線を引くことにはなります。ソフトウェア開発やプログラミングとあまりにも関係ない質問は、申し訳ないけれどもスタック・オーバーフロー向きではなくオフトピックである、という判断をすることになります。

オフトピックにするとして、我々だと他の Stack Exchange サイトに[移行](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10249/341401)することはできず、ただクローズすることになります。英語版の Stack Overflow だとソフトウェア開発と近いものの少し距離がある質問については、話題の範囲としてより適切な別のサイトが運営されており、そちらへ移行できる場合があります。しかし英語版と違って、今のところ日本語で運営されているサイトは私たちスタック・オーバーフローしかありません。したがって我々は Stack Exchange 上の他のサイトに誘導するという方法は使えません（使えたら、もう少しオントピックの範囲を狭くできるのですが……）。あるとしたら、[Area 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/) で提案してみるという遠回りな方法くらいでしょうか。私がよくやるのは、オフトピックを理由とする単なるクローズにしつつ Yahoo! 知恵袋や人力検索はてななど Stack Exchange の外の Q&A サイトにコメントで誘導するやり方です。

このため、ソフトウェア開発やプログラミングとはちょっと遠すぎるような電気回路の質問については、申し訳ないけれどオフトピックにしつつ、英語で運営されている別サイトや、Stack Exchange 外の日本語サイトを案内することになるのではないか、と考えています。具体的には、ソフトウェア開発をするのに使うデバイスの話や最終的にソフトウェアで処理することになる信号の話はオントピックぎみですが、オームの法則に代表されるような電磁気学の話やハンダ付けの仕方みたいな電気工作の話はオフトピックぎみ、かなあ、と個人的には考えています。今回話題になったコンデンサの話は私の中ではオフトピックぎみです。

この境界線の言語化に私は失敗し続けていて、うまく言葉にできていないので、どなたかうまく定義できたら教えてほしいです。言語化がうまくできるまでは、どうしても質問ごとに都度コミュニティで判断ということにならざるを得ないでしょう。

少しまぜっかえすと、この話が難しい理由のひとつには、どこまでを「ソフトウェア開発」や「プログラミング」と呼べるか少し揺らいでいるという面もあると考えています。ENIAC くらい昔の時代に遡ればパネル上でワイヤーの配線を変える操作がプログラミングにあたりますし、[自然計算](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_computing)のことを考えると光回路を組むとか粘菌を特定の条件下に置くみたいな操作もプログラミングと言えてしまうかもしれません。

なので個人的には、オントピックの範囲を少し広めに取りつつ、時代の変遷によって「プログラミング」や「ソフトウェア開発」の範囲が変わっていそうであれば都度オントピックの範囲も変えていくくらいが実行可能な運用ではないかな、と考えています。

これを電子回路の話に戻すと、先述したように、プログラミングに関係していそうならオントピック、ちょっと物理学や工作の話に寄りすぎていてプログラミングと距離がありそうならオフトピック、という判断を都度していくということになります。

似たような話として過去、[動画作成ソフトウェアの話題の範囲を考えたとき](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2589/19110)や [3D モデリングソフトの話題の範囲を考えたとき](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2694/19110)があります。このときも結局は同様に、それがプログラミングとは離れているならオフトピックという風に自分の中ではまとまったのでした。今回もコレと同じかな、と考えています。

Answer (score 2):

取り得る対処の方向としては以下の4つくらいでしょうか。

- オフトピックだったが以後オントピックとしてヘルプ等にも記載する
- オフトピックだがオフトピックのまま許容する
- オフトピックだが内容/投票/通報等により判断して記事毎に対処を決める
- オフトピックなのでクローズする

元の質問の人はオン/オフとか気にせず質問している印象があって、それはどうなのとか思いますがオフトピックである以外の内容は普通だし、印象は単なる個人の感想です。

---

私の意見は4番目の **オフトピックなのでクローズする** ですね。
英語のみで記述された質問をオフトピック処理するのと同様に考えています。

それらを専門に取り扱っている掲示板とかQ&Aサイトは無くても、私が同じ人の最初の純粋ハード系質問にコメントしたように、一応受け入れてくれるサイトはあるので。
[電圧についての質問です[CPUの創りかた]](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/88826/26370)

> 電気・電子回路の質問はここではオフトピックですね。[ここではどのようなトピックについて質問できますか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) 英語のサイトならこんなの [Electrical Engineering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/) がありますが、日本語でそれらを対象としているサイトは無かったような？ 詳しい個人・関連企業・あるいはなんでも扱っているようなサイトに移動した方が良いでしょう。[電子工作に詳しい方に質問](https://okwave.jp/qa/q9777249.html), [「電子回路」に関するQ＆A - Yahoo!知恵袋](https://chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/search?p=%E9%9B%BB%E5%AD%90%E5%9B%9E%E8%B7%AF&type=tag&tnum=1)

なお @774RR さんの言うように SPI, I2C や 微妙と言われる spresense(やarduino/raspberry piなど) とかはプログラミングやシステムにつながるものならばオントピックでしょう。

ただし許容する声が多いのであれば、**以後オントピックとしてヘルプ等にも記載する** と明確にした方が良いでしょう。